# Ansible: update bash env variable if it exist with latest values

Tags: bash, ansible

I have following excerpt from ansible playbook, where bash_profile env variable is updated in bash profile.

```
- name: Adding secret to bash_profile
  lineinfile: dest=/home/{{ app_user }}/.bash_profile line='export FERNET_KEY="{{fernet_key}}"' insertafter='EOF' state=present
  when: (fernet_key != "")

- name: Source the bash_profile file
  shell: source /home/{{ app_user }}/.bash_profile
  when: (fernet_key != "")
```

this is working as expected, but after a few test runs I am seeing that there are lots of duplicated 'FERNET_KEY' entry in `.bash_profile` for eg

```
cat .bash_profile
...
export FERNET_KEY="CM1oCh9S9giczWBR-e3fMZZoEA2jzFofexUTAeF6dWg="
export FERNET_KEY="ZH9QvlsgCRPJh78mUIBseCkJI-dtyx7CHATsSJWczjg="
export FERNET_KEY="yfke0mYJ7N9M34FUhSQSyZ6oBGG8b6Gw8UdnFFcyQ_4="
```

1. my question is, how can I update `FERNET_KEY` with latest values on new run and then deleting older `FERNET_KEY` values ?

Comment: `lineinfile: regexp: some_regex_that_matches_the_line_so_it_gets_removed`. There are literallly examples in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifiy `regexp`, so that the line is replaced. Also do not write such long lines.

```
- name: Adding secret to bash_profile
  lineinfile:
    dest: '/home/{{ app_user }}/.bash_profile'
    line: 'export FERNET_KEY="{{fernet_key}}"'
    regexp: '^export FERNET_KEY='
  when: (fernet_key != "")
```